# What kind of RAM is compatible with my system?

Tags: memory, compatibility, ddr3, ddr2

I want to upgrade my RAM but am not sure if I should/can get DDR2 or DDR3.

Sound like a stupid question, but CPU-Z is showing the following:

[image: screenshot of CPU-Z program’s output]

At the top, it is saying that it’s DDR3 RAM, but I have read that 667MHz speeds are only for DDR2, not DDR3.

Which can I use?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there's no DDR3 running at 667MHz? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddr3#JEDEC_standard_modules

Comment: @billc.cn Yeah, I just couldn't find any store offering DDR3 running at 667 MHz.

Comment: @billc.cn, that table you linked to shows the lowest value at 800MT/s. The confusion is between the data rate and the frequency.

Comment: @Synetech Oh, so I can buy `PC3-10700` which runs at up to `1333MHz` ?

Comment: @Scott, yes, but see my explanation below.

Comment: @Synetech I think you're not using correct technical terms here. (M)T is a unit for the number of memory transactions the memory can form not the frequency it runs at. DDR memory is able to perform double the number of transactions than its bus frequency because it does memory access on both the rising and falling edges of a clock signal, hence double data rate (DDR). It is technically wrong to say the memory runs at 1333MHz even if it is often misquoted by merchants like that.

Comment: @billc.cn, don’t tell me, I know all this. Tell Scott; he’s the one that read it somewhere. I was just trying to explain where the confusion may be stemming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll notice that the RAM is being run at *half* the speed expected. This, plus the fact that you are seeing four logical slots but only two physical ones points to the problem being due to the sided-ness of the RAM. The RAM stick you have is likely [double-sided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-sided_RAM), so the system is seeing two sticks instead of one (note, the sided-ness does not refer to the physical location of the chips).

Like most things in life, double-sided RAM has its pros and cons. On the one hand, it allows you to have more memory in fewer slots and at a cheaper price than single-sided RAM of the same size. On the other hand, only one side can be accessed at a time, which usually reduces the effective speed of the “two” sticks as a whole as opposed to two sticks of single-sided RAM (or one stick of single-sided, double-size RAM). It should not normally be half the speed, but perhaps that memory controller happens to be designed that way.

I’d have recommended check the BIOS to see if the memory-CPU speeds are set to auto, but there does not seem to be any such options (laptops usually limit such settings).

If you can get single-sided RAM instead, I suspect that the speed would be back to 1333MHz.

---

Your motherboard does indeed [support](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K53SD/#specifications) DDR3 RAM at up to 1333MHz, so you would be fine getting DDR3 RAM up to that speed.

The [`HMT351S6CFR8C-H9`](http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail_print.aspx?t=6m6RwcPKYkisQ2pSha+ZtA==&partno=HMT351S6CFR8C-H9) is [`PC3-10700`](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/274587-31-10600-10666-what-difference#t2045244) and runs at up to the maximum speed that your motherboards supports (1333MHz).

If you had more than one stick of RAM, then what would likely be happening is that you have mixed and matched the RAM sticks in your system, so your fastest RAM is being [throttled down](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26692795-memory-PC3-10700-667-MHz-ram-) to a speed that is compatible with your slowest RAM stick. Check the other sticks in the *Slot Selection* drop-down box.

If you remove the slower RAM stick(s), then your motherboard should be able to run the faster RAM at full-speed (though you may need to update the BIOS to make sure it has detected the new RAM).

If you only have one stick though, then something is going on since that stick *should* support 1333MHz as should your motherboard. Assuming that neither component is defective, then you need to examine the settings in the BIOS since something in there is probably causing it to run slower (you shouldn’t *have* to do anything; it should be automatic):

> From page 63 from the [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K53SD/E6591_K53SD_Emanual_Z103.zip):
>
> **Memory (RAM)**
>
> Additional memory will increase application performance by decreasing hard disk access. Visit an authorized service center or retailer for information on memory upgrades for your Notebook PC. Only purchase expansion modules from authorized retailers of this Notebook PC to ensure maximum compatibility and reliability. The BIOS automatically detects the amount of memory in the system and configures CMOS accordingly during the POST (Power-On-Self-Test) process. There is no hardware or software (including BIOS) setup required after the memory is installed.

First check your temperatures (e.g., with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)) to see if it is being throttled due to heat. Then, try loading your BIOS’ default settings and saving (note down the existing settings first). Also check for any turbo or boost settings that could affect it (though page A-12 of the manual indicates that it *shouldn’t* have any such features).

Comment: I got only one RAM stick used and its 4GB. So, if I want my motherboard to support RAM at full-speed I should remove the current RAM and buy the `PC3-10700` DDR3 RAM?

Comment: Restored my BIOS settings to the defaults - did not helped. I have also checked the temperatures, here is the screenshoot from the SpeedFan : `http://i.imgur.com/R3MwL.png`

Comment: Maybe it’s just CPU-Z. Try another program like [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) or [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/).

Comment: They are saying its `665MHz`, and the strange thing is that the memory usage is about 70% while running only browser (GChrome), Skype and IM.

Comment: *> the strange thing is that the memory usage is about 70% while running only browser (GChrome), Skype and IM*   That probably has no bearing on the speed, but it is worth looking into. Where are you seeing the usage? Check the Task Manager (`Ctrl+Shift+Esc`); make sure to click the *Show processes from all users* box.

Comment: Yes, I have checked them in the Task Manager before and the highest memory usage has: chrome.exe*32 - `150 636K`, svchost.exe - `117 050K` and Skype - `80 668K` all others are below 50K.

Comment: “All others”? *How many* others? They can add up you know. Did you try opening the calculator and summing them? I suspect that the usage isn’t an issue, but the speed *is*.

Comment: Is that stick of RAM the original one that came with the laptop or did you upgrade? If it’s the original, then you may want to contact Asus about this issue because the whole point to paying extra for a pre-built system is that the manufacturer is supposed to know what they are doing and use compatible parts and test so that it works correctly out-of-the-box. There doesn’t seem to be any legitimate reason for this be running slow, which mean that there’s something wrong with either the RAM or the motherboard. You can try getting a stick of 1333MHz RAM and testing it. Hopefully it’ll work.

Comment: It came with the laptop, I wasnt upgrading anything yet. I have already bought `1333MHz` RAM , I should receive it within 1-2 days... I can post an additional comment with the results then if you want.

Comment: Please do. Hopefully it’s just the stick you have that had an issue and was running slow because it is *much* easier and cheaper to fix than the motherboard. Moreover, maybe when the BIOS detects the new RAM, it will recalibrate (i.e., reset the ESCD/DMI/etc.) and work at full speed.

Comment: Yea, I hope that too. I will try to run the computer with those two sticks (current 4GB) and the new one will be 4GB also. Here is the RAM I've bought: `http://www.komputronik.pl/product/96393/Sprzet_komputerowy/Podzespoly/Kingston_4GB_1333MHz_DDR3_Non_ECC_CL9_SODIMM.html` you may wish to translate it, as I'm from Poland.

Comment: I have received a new RAM stick and CPU-Z is showing it is still working on `667MHz` (both of them).

Comment: Did you try with just the new one? If the new one works by itself, then it’s the old stick. If the new one by itself still shows 667MHz, then it’s the motherboard. At that point, you could try updating to the [latest BIOS](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K53SD/#download) (205) if you are not already using it, or if you are, then try simply re-flashing it.

Comment: Yea, and the strange thing is that `CPU-Z` is showing me 4 slots of RAM sticks, while I got only 2 slots in my motherboard. When I put the new RAM in the second (free) slot, the CPU-Z is showing it is installed in the third slot... I dont get it. I will try to remove the old stick as you said, and will post an another comment with the results - thank you for your time anyway! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check your mainboard manual and buy the RAM that the manufacturer recommends.

Comment: Couldn't find that in my mainboard manual. Here is the manual itself: `http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=K53SD&p=3&s=295&os=30&hashedid=9jm24aNcJp8vHonk`

Comment: Check the "Specifications" tab.